# Continuous Delivery with Jenkins: Deploy to production as manual step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are doing trunk-based development. So we just have a main branch.

There we have a Jenkins pipeline with this stages:

- Build -> Test -> Deploy to Test

Now I would like to add a manual stage that will deploy to Production. But I don't want to have stage that waits and blocks the pipeline. Just an optional manual stage that can be triggered by a user and that will deploy the build to production.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Pipeline:Input Step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) to achieve the deployment to production as manual step.

Here you can find an example for the same:

[How can I approve a deployment and add an optional delay for the deployment](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029265412-How-can-I-approve-a-deployment-and-add-an-optional-delay-for-the-deployment?page=24)

---

**Edited Answer**

---

Create a choice parameter using the option `This project is parameterised`  as below

[image]

Sample pipeline code with condition to run the stage or not:

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Deploy to Production') {
            when {
                expression { params.DEPLOY_TO_PRODUCTION == 'Yes' }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying to Production...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

1. When user select the `YES`, stage `Deploy to Production` will run

[image]
[image]

2. When user select the `NO`, stage `Deploy to Production` will not run

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is more or less what I already tried. The problem is that the pipeline will get stuck on the Approval stage and if someone aborts it the build will be marked as aborted.

Comment: And also the post actions will be called only if someone is approving

Comment: You can have a choice parameter (YES/NO) to ask for user input and put a condition on the parameter whether to execute the stage i.e. Deploy to Production or not.

Comment: How would this look like in a declarative pipeline?

Comment: I have edited the answer according to the above comment.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that in a declarative pipeline?

Comment: The above example is of declarative pipeline only.

Comment: Ok but I have to start this build manually? What if I want to build this base on a push in the git repo?

Comment: You can have webhooks configured for GitHub/Gitlab/BitBucket, to trigger the build automatically on git commit.

Comment: Sure but who is then setting the parameter?

Comment: You are trying here to achieve both the manual and automated task in the same time. This is not possible here.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That's what I wanted to know